# Repeating element in array x amount of times in same order

Tags: java, arrays

The question asks: "Write a method that takes 2 parameters: a String[] array, and an int numRepeats representing the number of times to repeat each element in the array. Return a new array with each element repeated numRepeats times."

For example:

```
repeatElements(new String[]{"hello", "world"}, 3)
```

Should return a new array with the elements:

```
["hello", "hello", "hello", "world", "world", "world"]
```

The code I have so far is:

```
public String[] repeatElements(String[] array, int numRepeats)
{
    String[] arr = new String[array.length * numRepeats];
    if(numRepeats == 0)
        return arr;

    if(array.length == 0)
        return arr;

    int m = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numRepeats; i++)
    {
        arr[m++] = array[0];
    }

    return arr;
}
```

My solution only works for some tests, not all of them. How do I fix my code so it can solve all tests given?

Comment: Seems you would need two nested loops, one over the `array` elements, and one for looping `numRepeats` times, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop only copies the first element of array. You were supposed to copy all of the elements `numRepeats` times. Something like,

```
for (String s : array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numRepeats; i++) {
        arr[m++] = s;
    }
}
```

Read that as for each `String s` in `array` assign `s` to position `m` in `arr` (and increment `m` afterward).

Answer (score 0):

You need another nested loop to repeat the elements of `array` for `numRepeats` number of times.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(repeatElements(new String[] { "hello", "world" }, 3)));

    }

    static String[] repeatElements(String[] array, int numRepeats) {
        String[] arr = new String[array.length * numRepeats];
        if (numRepeats == 0)
            return arr;

        if (array.length == 0)
            return arr;

        int m = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= numRepeats; j++) {
                arr[m++] = array[i];
            }
        }

        return arr;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[hello, hello, hello, world, world, world]
```

The nested loops can also be written as follows:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= numRepeats; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        arr[m++] = array[i];
    }
}
```